# The embed is not being sent and this is my code

Tags: python, discord.py, praw

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import praw

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = "myID",
                    client_secret = "mySecret",
                    username = "myUsername",
                    password = "myPassword",
                    user_agent = "myAgent")
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is ready, get ready to do wutever u want with it")

@bot.command
async def meme(ctx):
  all_submission = []
  subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
  top = subreddit.top(limit = 100)
  for submission in top:
    all_submission.append(submission)
  random_sub = random.choice(all_submission)
  name = random_sub.title
  url = random_sub.url
  em = discord.embed(title = name)
  em.set_image = url
  await ctx.embed(em)
  print("embed sent")

client.run("myToken")
```

when i send !meme in chat the bot is not responding and in the console it is not showing that the embed was sent either and no issues are coming up either please help and I did put in the actual tokens and stuff

Answer (score 1):

To send a embed you should use this:

```py
await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Edit: 
In the [discord.py docs for ctx](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#context) there is no `ctx.embed()`, so it should work. Thanks @FlexGames

Comment: (just as information for Nabhay) in the [discord.py docs for ctx](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#context) there is no `ctx.embed()` so this should be right

Comment: Thanks for completing, I will put it in my answer

Answer (score -1):

Send it like this as long as your data is correct it should work

```
  em = discord.embed(title = f"{name}", description="something", color=discord.Color.random)
  em.set_image = (url=f'{url}')
  await ctx.embed(embed=em)
  print("embed sent")
```